# How to increase spacing for a fraction

Tags: spacing

so I have the following:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\newcommand{\forceindent}{\leavevmode{\parindent=3em\indent}
\begin{document}
\forceindent $f(\chi_i)=\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{b\in G} {f}(b)\chi_i(b)$\\
\end{document}
```

However I want to increase the space of the horizontal line and |G| as it looks too involved

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\begin{document}

$f(\chi_i)=\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{b\in G} {f}(b)\chi_i(b)$


$f(\chi_i)=\frac{1}{\rule{0pt}{0.75em} |G|}\sum_{b\in G} {f}(b)\chi_i(b)$

\end{document}
```

[image]

(if too much, reduce 0.75em)

Comment: thank you, 0.65 is what I was looking for

Comment: Is this command not working for the numerator?